# How can I get the text of a hidden element in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following css and html...

```
.hide
{
 display:none;  
}

<div>
    <span class='kardashian hide'>Kimmy</span>
</div>
```

with the following jquery.

```
$('div').live('click', function(){
   alert($('kardashian', this).val());
});
```

If I remove the "hide" class I get "Kimmy" like I would expect but when it has the "hide" class I get nothing?
How can I get the text of a hidden element in Jquery?

Comment: Missing `.` Should be `$('.kardashian')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need a proper [`.class`](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) selector and [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) ([`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is for inputs), like this:

```
$('div').live('click', function(){
   alert($('.kardashian', this).text());
});
```

The visibility of the element doesn't really affect anything, it'll work whether it's hidden or not.

Answer (score 1):

[Use `.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead:

```
alert($('.kardashian', this).text());
```

The `.val()` method is used to get the value property of form inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the class indicator. Use `.kardashian`